# RecyclerView in fragment not taking scroll behaviours from nestedScollView in parent activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, nestedscrollview

I have an activity contains viewPager inside linear layout inside nestedScrollView and i have 3 fragments inside viewPager and inside each of it recyclerView
the problem is viewPager not taking the width of the fragment so when i scroll the recyclerView it is scrolling fine but in the particular part of activity
i don't know how to describe this problem correctly but i will insert some of image and code that will show the issue

**1- before scrolling**

[image]

**2- when scrolling nestedScrollView in parent activity**
[image]

3- when scrollin the fragment in viewPager

[image]

so i want when i scroll the tabs will scroll util reach to after tool bar
 i have tried so many solutions but it's not working

and this is the **parentActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="presenter"
        type="qatar2022.com.ramiissa.components.Profile.FriendProfile.Root.FriendProfilePresenter" />
</data>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/friend_profile_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/friend_profile_app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/friend_profile_collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:titleEnabled="false">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/friend_profile_cover"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/cover"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/friend_profile_tool_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/friend_profile_nested_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/friend_profile_username"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:text="Martha Harris"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_90" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/friend_profile_user_friend_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="5000 Friends"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_60" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/friend_profile_user_some_info"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Some info"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/friend_profile_user_message_button"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_primary"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/message"
                        android:drawableTint="@color/white"
                        android:paddingStart="20dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                        android:text="MESSAGE"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/friend_profile_friend_button"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_blue_gray"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/friend"
                        android:drawableTint="@color/white"
                        android:paddingStart="20dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                        android:text="ADD FRIEND"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/flag_icon" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/profile_nationality"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/profile_bottom_info_text_size" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/profile_bottom_info_text_size" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/friend_profile_nationality_value_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="Syria"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/profile_bottom_info_text_size" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/birthday_icon" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/profile_birthday"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/profile_bottom_info_text_size" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/profile_bottom_info_text_size" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/friend_profile_birthday_value_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="10-NOVEMBER"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/profile_bottom_info_text_size" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/relationship_icon" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/profile_relationship"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/profile_bottom_info_text_size" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/profile_bottom_info_text_size" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/friend_profile_relationship_value_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="Single"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/profile_bottom_info_text_size" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/work_icon" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/profile_working"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/profile_bottom_info_text_size" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/profile_bottom_info_text_size" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/friend_profile_work_value_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="Android Developer"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/profile_bottom_info_text_size" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/friend_profile_tab_layout"
                    style="@style/ProfileTabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@color/grey_300"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/pale_white" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/friend_profile_view_pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/friend_profile_user_photo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/example"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/friend_profile_app_bar_layout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: anyone can tell me why down vote the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you test my suggestion? Please put TabLayout and ViewPager outside the NestedScrollView and use NestedScrollView inside each fragment layout for parent layout.Of course you can put the page header to a partial and use it by include tag inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout but test first suggestion.

In main layout:

```
<AppBarLayout>    
 <CollapsingToolbarLayout android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
   <include layout="include_header" />
   <Toolbar />
 </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</AppBarLayout>
<ViewPager />
```

In include_header partial:

```
<FrameLayout android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
  <ConstraintLayout />
</FrameLayout>
```

I use ratio in constraint layout for background image header:
   **app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,4:3"**

This is my design and works perfectly.I had some design likes your design but I decided to change my way to get better result.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but i've already nested scroll view in fragments the problem is when i put viewpager outside nestedscrollview  it cover the nestedscrollview event when use layout anchor.

Comment: put the i don't understand the second suggestion

Comment: I'll edit my post. I have a layout likes your design and I solved some problems which I will put on post editing.